# Словарь технических терминов на русском языке

Tags: обсуждение, термины

Побывав на нескольких технических конференциях, я пришел к выводу, что огромное количество разработчиков программного обеспечения по какой-то причине не используют русскоязычные термины. Есть вероятность, что скорее всего они просто не знают про их существование.

Интересно еще то, как воспринимает ситуацию сообщество. В больших городах, таких как Санкт-Петербург или Москва, обычно разработчики не уделяет данному факту большого значения, но в Центральной России доклады, содержащие большое количество заимствованных слов (и особенно, образованных от них новых), вызывают сильное негодование.

Как мне кажется, в русском языке достаточно точных слов, чтобы сформировать «технический словарь разработчика», в котором не будет слов  «билдить», «оверайдить», «дженерики», «либа» и так далее.

Предлагаю составить такой словарь вместе! Формат:

**English Term**

- вариант перевода 1;
- вариант перевода 2;
- вариант перевода N;

Пожалуйста, пополняйте ответ терминами, которые вы слышите непрерывно день за днем на работе. Если прямого перевода нет, то сообщество может придумать новый термин и его вариации (существительное, прилагательное, глагол и т. д.). Если на момент добавления термина вы не можете подобрать хороший перевод, пожалуйста, добавляйте только термин. Уверен, сообщество поможет найти перевод.

Давайте вместе сделаем нашу ежедневную профессиональную речь красивей и понятней!

**Обновление**

На мой взгляд, обсуждать переводы конкретных терминов можно либо в [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--), либо [задав вопрос](/questions/ask).

**Почему нам нужен такой словарь?**

Уверен, причин тому много. Вот несколько из них

- На мой взгляд, отделение языков необходимо, так как в текущем виде коверкается как русский, так и английский. Взять хотя бы произношение, например, слова «функция». Мы используем русскоязычную версию, согласитесь, никто не говорит «фанкция» - выгляди смешно и нелепо. Вот примерно также звучит «билдить», просто привыкаем, к сожалению.
- Проблема использования слов вроде «билдить» кроется не в развитии языка, а в незнании существующего - словарный запас не такой богатый, как хотелось бы. Задача данной публикации - дать сообществу выбор: использовать русскоязычные слова или англоязычные. Из своего опыта могу сказать, что использование русскоязычных вариантов позволит повысить понимание между говорящим и слушающим и сделать речь приятнее.

Comment: Готовлюсь тут к конфе, спрашиваю у русского разработчика виртуальной машины HotSpot, как правильно на русском называть компиляторы C1 и C2 — «цэ-один» или «си-один». Он ответил, что всегда даже на русскоязычных конференциях говорит «си-ван» и «си-ту». Раз сам разработчик так говорит, спорить показалось неуместно :-)

Comment: "С" - соглашусь, произношение "си", а не "цэ". Но цифры, я бы скорее всего по-русски произносил. Тут идея, все таки, в переводе терминов. Названия языков и т. д, конечно, можно произносить по разному.

Comment: А где обсуждать перевод? Кстати, если сборка = build, то в контексте .NET assembly = ?

Comment: Заходите [сюда](http://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx), вбиваете нужное слово, выбираете English и Russian и имеете счастье.

Comment: @TagirValeev Посмотрел, инструмент хороший, но надобность словаря, на мой взгляд, не отменят.

Comment: Бесполезно, в реальном мире все технические термины связанные с компьютерами полиморфны и элементарно переопределяются на месте. Например язык программирования FORTH вообще основан на этом соображении. Там каждый создает свой словарь, попутно наделяя слова нужным для решения задачи смыслами. Например в моем воображаемом словаре этот длинный комментарий осуществляет пузырьковую сортировку. Такой подход позволяет избавиться от всяких ненужных вещей вроде стандартов и учебников, окунуться в чистый первобытный мир, работает уже 40+ лет и вообще весьма православен.

Comment: @igumnov то-то FORTH так популярен. Use the FORTH, Luke!

Comment: @Nick В его популярности как раз и заключена темная сторона силы. Этим комментарием вы уже написали валидную форт программу. Если считать его за условный переход, а этот за инкремент, то мы получим вполне себе годный эзотерический диалект, даже не имея никакой изначальной цели, желания или мотивации сделать это. И да, нужно было конечно так: `LUKE THE FORTH USE`

Comment: Я абсолютно за то, чтобы создать и наполнить словарь терминов, но категорически против замещения англицизмов в IT-терминологии русскоязычными аналогами. Наша организация часто пишет ТЗ и ИТТ сразу на двух языках, разделяя лист вертикально пополам. Слева - русский, справа английский язык. Один  тот же по содержанию текст на английском языке кончается на 40й странице, а на русском тянется до 60й!. Это -  живые человекочасы из воздуха - у нас длиннее слова! Русификация терминов неизбежно увеличит количество длиных терминов, ведь простейшая "mouse"- это "устройство позиционирования курсора".

Comment: @AnatolyNikolaev Неоспоримо, текст на русском языке длиннее. Когда я участвовал в написании документации мы решали данный вопрос за счет введения аббревиатур и терминов (уверен, тут вы на порядок опытнее меня), как раз то, что и делают многие англоязычные слова. Таким обозом, на мой взгляд, вопрос в подходе.

Comment: Согласен, в чем то вы правы. Предлагаю для сохранения структуры словаря подчистить тему от комментариев и создать отдельный чат для обсуждения терминов. Так же, возможно, имеет смысл разбить словарь побуквенно на отдельные сообщения. Кроме того, предлагаю не включать в словарь акронимы. Словарь акронимов - это отдельный большой словарь.

Comment: @AnatolyNikolaev На мой взгляд, разбиение на отдельные ответы ухудшит читаемость. С удовольствием выучу правильные акронимы. Пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь добавлять их!

Comment: ИМХО данная инициатива, хотя и неплохая, но никак не относится к тематике и формату SO и ей здесь не место.

Comment: @Kromster Почему же! (1) Мы переводим интерфейс сайта и нам нужен глоссарий. (2) При правки, как минимум я, часто заменяю заимствованные слова. Уверен, не все знают русскоязычные термины и здорово, что у нас есть место, где мы можем поделиться своими знаниями.

Comment: [Чат-комната для обсуждения этого вопроса](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56975/)

Answer (score 16):

#### A

**Activity**

- *сущ.* операция (в андроид) <sup>[источник](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html?hl=ru)</sup>.

**Alias**

- *сущ.* псевдоним.

**Append**

- *гл.* вставить в конец [списка].

**Application**

- *сущ.* приложение.

**Array**

- *сущ.* массив.

**Attach**

- *гл.* прикрепить (вложение);
- *гл.* подключиться (начать отладку).

---

#### B

**Back End Developer**

- *сущ.* разработчик серверной части.

**Background**

- *сущ.* фон.

**Background** [in `field`]

- *сущ.* профессиональное прошлое, опыт [в `области`].

**Backtrace**

- *сущ.* трассировка.

**Bar**

- *сущ.* панель (см. также *side-bar*).

**Big Data**

- большие данные.

**Binding**

- привязка.

**Bitmap**

**Bit rate**

- количество бит в секунду (при передаче или обработке данных), битрейт;
- "ширина" канала передачи данных, который требуется для передачи аудио или видео содержимого.

**Blacklist**

- чёрный список.

**Bold**

- *прил.* полужирный.

**Boolean, Bool**

- *прил.* логический (тип данных).

**Bootstrap**

- *сущ.* загрузка, начальная загрузка.

**Bridge**

- *сущ.* [сетевой] мост.

**Вroadcasting**

- *сущ.* широковещание, *прил.* широковещательный.

**Browser**

- *сущ.* браузер, обозреватель.

**Bruteforce**

- (перебор) грубой силой.

**Bug**

- *сущ.* ошибка, дефект.

**Build**

- *сущ.* сборка, *гл.* собирать.

**Bus**

- *сущ.* шина.

**Button**

- *сущ.* кнопка.

---

#### C

**CAPTCHA**

**Case**

- *сущ.* случай;
- *сущ.* вариант.

**Casting**

- *сущ.* приведение (типов).

**Character**

- *сущ.* символ, буква.

**Chart**

- *сущ.* диаграмма.

**Checkbox**

- *сущ.* флажок [элемент интерфейса].

**Child**

- *сущ.* потомок, наследник.

**Click**

- *сущ.* щелчок.

**Clipboard**

- *сущ.* буфер обмена.

**Cloud**

- *сущ.* облако.

**Cloud Computing**

- *сущ.* облачные вычисления.

**Communication**

- *сущ.* взаимодействие

**Commit**

- *сущ.* фиксация, *гл.* зафиксировать.

**Compile**

- *гл.* компилировать.

**Connection**

- *сущ.* подключение, соединение.

**Connector**

- *сущ.* разъём.

**Content**

- *сущ.* содержимое, содержание.

**Contributor**

- *сущ.* участник [проекта].

**Control**

- *сущ.* управление.
- *сущ.* элемент управления.

**Crash**

- аварийное завершение;
- *сущ.* падение.

**Custom**

- *прил.* нестандартный, пользовательский.

---

#### D

**Data**

- *сущ.* данные.

**Database Dump**

- *сущ.* снимок базы данных.

**Datasheet**

- *сущ.* спецификация.

**Debugger**

- *сущ.* отладчик.

**Declaration**

- *сущ.* объявление.

**Default**

- *нар.* по умолчанию.

**Delimiter**

- *сущ.* разделитель.

**Dependence**

- *сущ.* зависимость.

**Deployment**

- *сущ.* развёртывание.

**Description**

- *сущ.* описание.

**Descriptor**

- *сущ.* описатель.

**Design Pattern**

- *сущ.* шаблон проектирования.

**Desktop**

- рабочий стол;
- настольный компьютер.

**Developer**

- *сущ.* разработчик.

**Device**

- *сущ.* устройство.

**DevOps**

**Dump**

- *сущ.* снимок, слепок.
- *гл.* сохранить состояние в файл

**Drive**

- *сущ.* привод.

**Driver**

- *сущ.* драйвер

---

#### E

**Engine**

- *сущ.* движок.

**Entity**

- *сущ.* сущность.

**Enumerate**

- *гл.* перечислять, перебирать [последовательно].

**Environment**

- *сущ.* окружение.

**Event**

- *сущ.* событие.

**Exception**

- *сущ.* исключение.

**Expand**

- *гл.* развернуть.

---

#### F

**Fail**

- *сущ.* провал (неудача);
- *сущ.* падение.

**False**

- *сущ.* ложь (логическое значение).

**Feature**

- *сущ.* возможность, функциональность [программы / устройства];
- *сущ.* особенность, признак.
- *сущ.* фишка *(разг.)*

**Feedback**

- *сущ.* отклик (на что-либо);
- обратная связь.

**Fragment**

- *сущ.* фрагмент (в андроид) <sup>[источник](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments?hl=ru)</sup>.

**Field**

- *сущ.* поле.

**Fill**

- *сущ.* заливка, *гл.* залить, заполнить

**Firmware**

- *сущ.* прошивка.

**Font**

- *сущ.* шрифт.

**Footer**

- *сущ.* нижний колонтитул.
- *сущ.* подвал [страницы].

**Foreground**

- передний план.

**Forwarding**

- *сущ.* пробрасывание, пересылка.

**Frames Per Second (FPS)**

- кадров в секунду, частота кадров.

**Framework**

- *сущ.* каркас (для быстрой разработки).

**Freeware**

- *сущ.* бесплатное ПО.

**Front End Developer**

- *сущ.* разработчик клиентской части.

---

#### G

**Generic**

- *сущ.* обобщение, обобщённый тип.

**Gravity**

**Grid**

- *сущ.* сетка.

**GUI**

- *сущ.* графический [пользовательский] интерфейс.

**Guide**

- *сущ.* учебник;
- *сущ.* руководство;
- *сущ.* инструкция.

---

#### H

**Handler**

- *сущ.* обработчик.

**Hardware**

- аппаратное обеспечение;
- *сущ.* железо *(разг.)*.

**Hash**

**Header**

- *сущ.* верхний колонтитул.
- *сущ.* шапка [страницы];
- *сущ.* заголовок.

**Header file**

- *сущ.* заголовочный файл.

**Heap**

- *сущ.* куча.

**Hibernation**

- спящий режим.

**Highlight**

- *сущ.* подсветка, выделение.

**Hint**

- *сущ.* подсказка.

**Hotkey**

- горячая клавиша;
- быстрая клавиша.

**Hub**

- *сущ.* [сетевой] концентратор, разветвитель

---

#### I

**Icon**

- *сущ.* иконка, значок.

**Identifier (ID)**

- *сущ.* идентификатор.

**Image**

- *сущ.* изображение;
- *сущ.* образ [диска, физического носителя].

**Implement**

- *гл.* реализовать.

**Inline**

- *прил.* встраиваемая [функция]
- *прил.* встроенная [цитата]

**Input**

- *сущ.* поле ввода.

**Input/output (IO)**

- ввод/вывод.

**Insert**

- *сущ.* врезка (верстка);
- *гл.* вставить.

**Installation**

- *сущ.* установка.

**Integer**

- *сущ.* целое (число).

**Integrated development environment (IDE)**

- *сущ.* [интегрированная] среда разработки.

**Interruption**

- *сущ.* прерывание.

**Issue**

- *сущ.* дефект, проблема;
- *сущ.* задача;
- *гл.* выдать, выпустить [сертификат].

**Item**

- *сущ.* элемент.

**Iterate**

**Iteration**

---

#### J

**Job**

- *сущ.* задача, задание.

**Join**

- *гл.* присоединиться, соединять.

**Junior**

- младший разработчик.

---

#### K

---

#### L

**Label**

- *сущ.* метка.

**Lag**

- *сущ.* задержка.

**Launcher**

- *сущ.* загрузчик.

**Layer**

- *сущ.* слой.

**Layout**

- *сущ.* раскладка;
- *сущ.* разметка, макет.

**Library**

- *сущ.* библиотека.

**Link**

- *сущ.* ссылка.

**List**

- *сущ.* список.

**Loading**

- *сущ.* загрузка.

**Log**

- *сущ.* журнал.

**Logging**

- *сущ.* журналирование.
- *сущ.* протоколирование.

**Login**

- *сущ.* вход (в систему);
- *сущ.* имя (пользователя);
- *гл.* войти в систему.

**Loop**

- *сущ.* цикл.

---

#### M

**Malware**

- *сущ.* вредоносное ПО, зловредное ПО, зловред *(разг.)*.

**Man in the middle (MITM)**

- человек посередине (вид атаки).

**Manual**

- *сущ.* руководство.

**Map**

- *сущ.* отображение (множеств), карта;
- *гл.* отобразить, сопоставить (множества);
- ассоциативный массив;

**Master**

- *сущ.* ведущий (режим работы программы / устройства).

**Master boot record (MBR)**

- главная загрузочная запись.

**Match**

- *сущ.* совпадение [при поиске]
- *гл.* сопоставлять

**Media**

- *сущ.* носитель.

**Merge**

- *гл.* объединять;
- *гл.* сливать (сливать вместе, слиться воедино).

**Message**

- *сущ.* сообщение.

**Middle**

**Minimize**

- *гл.* свернуть.

**Mock** (в контексте тестирования)

- *сущ.* имитация, подмена
- *гл.* имитировать, подменять, подменять на имитацию

**Mode**

- *сущ.* режим.

**Monitoring**

**Mutex**

---

#### N

**Network**

- *сущ.* [компьютерная] сеть.

**Notification**

- *сущ.* уведомление.

**Node**

- *сущ.* узел.

---

#### O

**Offline**

- *прил.* автономный;
- не в сети.

**Online**

- *прил.* интерактивный;
- в сети.

**Open Source**

- *сущ.* открытый код (ОтКод).

**Output**

- *сущ.* вывод.

**Overhead**

- *сущ.* оверхед — накладные расходы (дополнительное время, которое занимает выполнение используемой функции).

**Overloading**

- *сущ.* перегрузка.

**Override**

- *гл.* переопределять.

---

#### P

**Pagination**

- постраничная навигация.

**Parent**

- *сущ.* родитель.

**Parse**

- *гл.* [синтаксически] разбирать (на структуры данных, дерево разбора, и т. п.).

**Partition**

- *сущ.* раздел.

**Password**

- *сущ.* пароль.

**Patch**

- *сущ.* заплатка, исправление

**Patching cord (Patch cord)**

- коммутационный шнур, коммутационный кабель.

**Picture**

- *сущ.* картинка.

**Pin**

- *сущ.* вывод, ножка.

**Pinout**

- *сущ.*_ "распиновка", описание назначения выводов (микросхемы, микроконтроллера и т.д.)

**Pipe**

- *сущ.* канал, конвейер.

**Pipeline**

- *сущ.* конвейер

**Plugin**

- *сущ.* расширение, подключаемый модуль.

**Pointer**

- *сущ.* указатель.

**Pool**

**Popup**

- *сущ.* всплывающее окно

**Private**

- *прил.* закрытый (уровень доступа).

**Processing**

- *сущ.* обработка.

**Programmer**

- *сущ.* программист.

**Property**

- *сущ.* свойство.

**Proprietary**

- *прил.* собственническое [ПО].

**Protected**

- *прил.* защищённый (уровень доступа).

**Proxy**

**Public**

- *прил.* публичный, общий, открытый (уровень доступа).

**Push**

---

#### Q

**Query**

- *сущ.* запрос.

---

#### R

**Radio button**

- *сущ.* переключатель [элемент интерфейса].

**Random**

- *прил.* произвольный [доступ];
- *прил.* случайное [значение].

**Range**

- *сущ.* диапазон.

**Reboot**

- *сущ.* перезапуск, перезагрузка.

**Redirect**

- *гл.* перенаправлять, переадресовывать;
- *сущ.* перенаправление, переадресация.

**Reengineering**

**Refactoring**

**Reference**

- *сущ.* ссылка.

**Release**

- *сущ.* выпуск.
- *прил.* выпускной (сборка, версия).

**Rendering**

- *сущ.* отрисовка, визуализация.

**Repeater**

- *сущ.* повторитель.

**Report**

- *сущ.* отчёт.

**Request**

- *сущ.* запрос.

**Response**

- *сущ.* ответ.

**Restart**

- *сущ.* перезапуск, перезагрузка.

**Root**

- *сущ.* корень, начало, суперпользователь (безопасность);
- *прил.* корневой (элемент).

**Routine**

**Route**

- *сущ.* маршрут.

**Router**

- *сущ.* маршрутизатор.

**Run**

- *сущ.* запуск, *гл.* запустить.

---

#### S

**Salt**

- *сущ.* соль, модификатор (криптография).

**Scale**

- *сущ.* масштаб.

**Scheduler**

- *сущ.* планировщик.

**Scientist**

- *сущ.* ученый.

**Screen**

- *сущ.* экран.

**Script**

- *сущ.* сценарий.

**Scroll**

- *сущ.* прокрутка.

**Scrollbar**

- *сущ.* полоса прокрутки.

**Seal**

- *сущ.* пломба, печать.

**Sealed**

- *прил.* запечатанный.

**Search**

- *сущ.* поиск.

**Select**

- *сущ.* выбор, *гл.* выбрать.

**Selector**

**Sender**

- *сущ.* отправитель.

**Senjor**

- старший разработчик.

**Sensor**

- *сущ.* сенсор, датчик.

**Separator**

- *сущ.* разделитель.

**Security**

- *сущ.* безопасность.

**Server**

**Service**

- *сущ.* сервис;
- *сущ.* служба (тип фоновых программ ОС Windows).

**Settings**

- *сущ.* настройки.

**Share**

- *сущ.* общий ресурс.
- *гл.* публиковать, делать общим, предоставлять доступ.
- *гл.* совместно использовать.

**Shareware**

**Shutdown**

- *сущ.* завершение работы, выключение.

**[Keyboard] shortcut**

- *см. "Hotkey"*

**Side-bar**

- боковая панель.

**Singleton**

- *сущ.* одиночка (шаблон проектирования).

**Site**

**Size**

- *сущ.* размер.

**Slave**

- *сущ.* ведомый (режим работы программы / устройства).

**Sliding**

**Snippet**

**Software**

- ПО (программное обеспечение).

**Socket**

- *сущ.* сокет *(устоявшееся разг.)* (в контексте сетевого программирования)
- *сущ.* разъём, гнездо, розетка (в контексте аппаратного обеспечения)

**Space**

- *сущ.* пространство;
- *сущ.* [клавиша] «пробел».

**Spacer**

**Splash screen**

- *сущ.* стартовый экран, заставка.

**SQL injection**

- внедрение SQL-кода (вид уязвимостей).

**Startup**

- *сущ.* запуск.

**Storage**

- *сущ.* хранилище.

**Stream**

- *сущ.* поток [данных] (например, файловый поток).

**String**

- *сущ.* [текстовая] строка.

**Support**

- *сущ.* поддержка.

**Switch**

- *сущ.* [сетевой] коммутатор.

---

#### T

**Tab**

- *сущ.* вкладка;
- *сущ.* клавиша табуляции на клавиатуре.

**Tag**

- *сущ.* метка.

**Task**

- *сущ.* задача.

**Team**

- *сущ.* команда (участников).

**Team leader (Team Lead, Teamlead)**

- руководитель команды.

**Template**

- *сущ.* шаблон (класса, сайта и т. д.)

**Terminate**

- *сущ.* завершить [принудительно].

**Terminator**

- *сущ.* ограничитель.

**Thread**

- *сущ.* поток, нить [выполнения] (при параллельной обработке).

**Ticket**

**Timeout**

**Token**

**Tool**

- *сущ.* инструмент.

**Tooltip**

- всплывающая подсказка.

**Touch Screen (Touchscreen)**

- сенсорный экран.

**Tracking**

- *сущ.* отслеживание.

**Tray**

**True**

- *сущ.* истина (логическое значение).

**Tutorial**

- урок, руководство.

**Typedef** (С++)

- *сущ.* псевдоним.

**Tweak**

---

#### U

**Unit**

- *сущ.* модуль.

**Unit test**

- *сущ.* модульный тест.

**Update**

- *сущ.* обновление.

**URL**

- *сущ.* единый указатель ресурсов.

**Usability**

- *сущ.* удобство использования.

**Use**

- *гл.* использовать.

**User**

- *сущ.* пользователь

**User Experience**

- *сущ.* опыт использования.

**User Interface (UI)**

- *сущ.* пользовательский интерфейс.

---

#### V

**Validation**

**Value**

- *сущ.* значение.

**View**

- *сущ.* представление;
- *гл.* просматривать.

**Viewer**

- *сущ.* просмотрщик.

**Volume**

- *сущ.* том, [логический] диск.

---

#### W

**Warning**

- *сущ.* предупреждение.

**Whitelist**

- белый список.

**Widget**

- *сущ.* [визуальный] элемент управления.

**Wildcard**

- *сущ.* символ подстановки.

**Wireless**

- *прил.* беспроводной.

**Workaround**

- *сущ.* обходное решение.

**Wrap**

---

#### X

---

#### Y

---

#### Z

Comment: опыт пользователя — слишком буквально, на мой взгяд. Обычно речь идет об удобстве, эргономике, usability.

Comment: Вот и смысл если "эргономика" и "юзабилити" - заимствованные слова?

Comment: @AnatolyNikolaev Как на счет «удобство использования»?

Comment: @NickVolynkin На сколько я могу судить, в англоязычном пространстве существует термин «experience», к которому относят любой опыт. Например, «Berlin experience» - любые эмоции и новые впечатления полученные в городе. Как мне кажется, в прямом понимании «User experience» - опыт пользователя или опыт использования (по аналогии, что мы испытываем, когда пользуемся например, приложением). Возможно, слово «опыт» не самое лучшее. Буду рад подсказке!

Comment: Один из вариантов, предложенных Google Translate - `взаимодействие с пользователем`

Comment: Пора делить на буквы?

Comment: "Bug" это не "ошибка", а "отказ" или "дефект". Ошибки допускают люди, из-за которых в программах происходят отказы и дефекты.

Comment: @AnatolyNikolaev "эргономика" хоть и заимствованное слово - но это не мешает ему быть русским

Comment: @PavelMayorov на всякий случай http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56975/

Comment: Победи СССР в гонке технологий - заимствовали бы наши слова. А так - пустая затея, хотя отлично подойдё направлять новичков.

Comment: @Other Почему же пустая? Как минимум в нашем сообществе будем использовать правильные слова! Что будет дальше, увидим!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, да? Переборем привычки, саму модель речи и будем править вопросы/ответы по этому поводу? Это вряд ли, импорт терминов всё ещё с английского, особенно если какой-то термин не имеет аналогов (особенно новые понятия) или имеет, но в размере 10-и слов.

Comment: кажется, этот список надо бы подсократить, убрав очевидные переводы, которые как правило не вызывают затруднений

Comment: @mymedia Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом определить, является ли _для всех_ данный перевод очевидным? Если список слишком длинный, можно разбить ответ на несколько букв в каждом, например, по 10.

Comment: @mymedia нет, не нужно. Одна из проблем индустрии как раз в том, что англицизмы нередко используются даже вместо очевидных переводов.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, к сожалению, у меня нету универсального рецепта, как выяснить, является ли конкретный перевод очевидным или нет. Но можно, например, смотреть в какой-нибудь ещё словарь, и если первый вариант перевода из стороннего словаря совпадает с нашим, то можно считать, что он очевидный. Например, перевод слова "bug" как "дефект" не является очевидным, потому что в таком варианте в [словаре ABBYY Lingvo](https://www.lingvolive.com/ru-ru/translate/en-ru/bug) он указан только на шестом месте, не на первом. А вот, скажем, слово "update" имеет очевидный перевод как "обновление".

Comment: Разбивать наш словарь на несколько ответов, мне не кажется, хорошей идеей, т.к. из-за может сбиться сортировка по алфавиту.

Comment: @D-side, сомневаюсь, что проблему проникновения англицизмов в наш язык можно решить _ещё одним_ словарём :(

Comment: Мне кажется, неплохой идей было бы воспользоваться уже готовыми словарями и глоссариями - они зачастую составлены вполне сносно. Одним из таких решений может стать терминологическая база от Майкрософт. Её разрешено использовать для свободного ознакомления в интерактивном режиме. https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/language

Comment: @mymedia крайне интересная ссылка, большое спасибо! Преимущество нашего подхода все–таки есть: мы всегда можем сами добавить новый термин.

Comment: @АртёмИонаш по какому алфавиту N идёт перед M?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Прошу прощения, что-то меня переклинило.