# Вопросы о профессиональной терминологии и переводе технических терминов

Tags: обсуждение, тематика

Встретил вот такой вопрос: [Как будет на английском слово "вёрстка"?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/78706/181472)

Сам недавно искал ответ на этот вопрос и нашёл не сразу (ответ — markup). Сейчас наткнулся на вопрос и затрудняюсь определить его соответствие нашей тематике.

Коллеги, как вы считаете, стоит ли нам задавать и отвечать на вопросы о профессиональной терминологии и переводе технических терминов? Мы обсуждали переводы на Мете и здесь даже есть [вопрос-словарь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1267/). А что насчёт основного сайта?

Если да, то каковы границы? Например, будем ли мы делать ревью технической документации? Я могу и охотно делал бы, причём могу вывести достаточно четкие требования и критерии качества для некоторых документов.

Comment: Не [эту](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1267/) ли проблему пытаетесь решить?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: я упомянул этот вопрос. Но, думаю, он не охватывает весь круг вопросов и проблем, связанных с терминологией и документацией. К тому же, там нельзя дать развернутые инструкции по использованию.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

А собственно, почему бы и нет? Пусть будет.

Comment: Ну хоть по этому вопросу без холиваров.

Comment: Принял ответ. Если когда-нибудь внезапно перевесит другой ответ, вернемся к обсуждению.

Answer (score 1):

Если мы говорим на примере вопроса из сабжа, то:

1. Трактовка вопроса не ясна. Не понятно о какой именно вёрстке говорится. Это может быть и Pagination и layout, да что угодно.
2. Однозначно даже на правильно поставленный вопрос не ответить в этом вопросе. Если речь про веб вёртску, то это front-end developer может быть. Хотя в англоязычной литературе это может писать про вёртску "I need developed " или же "I need several PSD pages to be converted to HTML".
3. К тому же этот вопрос не формата SO.

Так что нет, я против подобных вопросов.