# Нужны ли переводы на Stack Overflow? Если да, какой вы видите систему?

Tags: обсуждение, перевод-содержимого

Несколько недель назад, мы начали обсуждать очень важную тему [автопереводов содержимого Stack Overflow англиском](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8267/6) на русский язык. Огромное спасибо всем, кто поделился мыслями! Ваши идеи сильно изменили мое представление о проблеме.

Автопереводы вызвали большой интерес не только в нашем сообществе, но и среди моих коллег внутри компании. Они разделяют позицию высказавшихся на Мете о том, что нам необходимо лучше работать с SEO–составляющей сайта. Другой отзыв коллег — автопереводы мертвы: нет людей, кто исправит, закроет, удалит ненужное, нет авторства. Сообщество и содержимое неразрывно связаны. Если участникам интересны переводы, то необходимо создать для них необходимые инструменты и соответствующую инфраструктуру.

Думая над проблемой и смотря на отзыв [@Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy)

> [не можешь победить - возглавь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8267/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-stack-overflow-%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D0%B1-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5#comment34104_8267)

Появился вопрос:

> Если представить, что завтра мы реализуем возможность работать с [автоматизированными как–либо] переводами, как будет выглядеть эта система в рамках Stack Overflow? Так, чтобы соответствовала миссии проекта, была по нраву участникам сообщества и создавала больше *качественных* знаний по программированию?

Пожалуйста, предложите ваше видение системы, которой бы вы действительно *пользовались* сами, чтобы она позволяла работать над переводами (возможно, как–то автоматизированно) в рамках Stack Overflow не нарушая основных принципов системы.

Будет здорово увидеть ваши мысли! Особенно интересно, какие вы предложили бы решения для:

- репутации (кто получает репутацию, когда, за что);
- проверки сделанных переводов;
- авторства переводов (длительной поддержки содержимого в контексте правок, дополнений, новых ответов);
- интеграции с «не переводами».

Смелые решения приветствуются! =)

Comment: Кстати очень важный момент: бывает задают вопрос "как мне сделать то-то то-то". И в комментариях дают ссылку на англоязычный stackoverflow, типо здесь есть решение. А ведь можно было перевести принятый ответ.

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev Спасибо! Отличное замечание.

Comment: Также может стоить рассмотреть тип "тревоги" ответ есть на enSO или других языках. И если какое-то время ответ не поступил, то добавить вопрос в очередь на перевод или типо того.

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev Обалденная механика, спасибо!

Comment: Почему этого поста нет на MSE? Вроде бы планировалось подобное выносить именно туда, а на локализованных сайтах делать перевод.

Comment: @älёxölüt Никто не переводит на русский! Тема для нас очень актуальная. Конечно, думаю в ближайшее время и в других сообществах поднимется этот вопрос.

Comment: Тема, как я понимаю, актуальна для любых неанглоязычных сообществ. Или для ruSO сильнее всех?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, а это никак не пересекается с ассоциациями?

Comment: @älёxölüt Мне кажется, для нас как–то более критично. Как минимум, блокируем публикацию на такие ссылки пока только мы.

Comment: @Grundy Пересечения однозначно есть, вы правы.

Comment: @älёxölüt, как вариант, на других языках пока не завелись сайты с автопереводами и нет необходимости подсказывать им идею :)

Comment: @Qwertiy по сути такие сайты это проблема ранжирование поисковиков в русскоязычном сегменте. У нас если слова местами поменять (с сохранением смысла), то поисковик считает уже её как другую статью. В других языках я не замечал такое. Так что может такая проблема будет только у нас.

Comment: @Qwertiy я посмотрел описание [плагина](https://github.com/Taraflex/Back2stackoverflow) по ссылке из предыдущего вопроса, и там далеко не только русский язык.

Comment: автоматические переводы ужасны, нечитабельны и неинформативны. Не все то что написано русскими буквами, является русским языком. Даже частично такая форма перевода не должна существовать в принципе. При поиске в google постоянно выскакивает на первых строчках какой-то русский сайт где как раз в 100% случаев перевод с SO. Настолько раздражает текст, что искал возможность удалить из поиска данный сайт.

Answer (score 8):

На мой взгляд не нужно реализовывать полностью автоматические переводы. Многие слова не имеют смысла в дословном переводе и должны интерпретироваться в контексте. Скорее всего имеет смысл добавлять рейтинговые вопросы с enSO и добавлять их в некую очередь, по аналогии с вопросами.
Репутацию должен получать непосредственно переводчик, после одобрения перевода, т.е. один и тот-же вопрос может быть переведен несколькими переводчиками и после "голосования" лучший перевод публикуется.
Ссылка на оригинальный вопрос должна присутствовать в тексте для длительной поддержки, дополнений и т.д.. Таким образом можно будет быстро определить несоответствие оригинала и перевода в дальнейшем.

---

#### Дополнение

В комментариях указывается на возможность использования нейросети для автоматического перевода, но на мой взгляд одно дело переводить документацию, написанную на литературном языке и как-бы то ни было, по одной тематике, а другое дело вопросы и ответы, где иногда, что называется "на пальцах" объясняются различные вещи. Можно перевести любую документацию автоматическим переводом и увидеть, что спорных моментов предостаточно. Так-же меня терзают сомненья по поводу реализации ресурсоёмких вещей на ruSO, таких как нейросети и т.п..
На текущий момент, для перевода необходимо запостить вопрос и на него самому же ответить, что нисколько не гарантирует качество перевода. И конечно переводы, которые будут отклонены, никоим образом не должны бить по репутации переводчика.

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв! Идея с репутацией, как мне кажется, правильная. Единственное, на мой взгляд, участники не будут переводить если не будут уверены, что их работа будет опубликована. Перевод — дело довольно сложное и часто занимает больше времени, чем написание ответа. Что думаете?

Comment: В противном случае будет ситуация когда, "кто первый - того и тапочки". Если перевод качественный, а не Google.Переводчик, то у переводчиков не должна возникать неуверенность или сомнения. Конечно в будущем будут возникать спорные моменты, но это рабочий процесс и на это будет голосование.

Comment: «слова не имеют смысла в дословном переводе и должны интерпретироваться в контексте» — современные системы вполне с этим справляются, умеют понимать контекст и выбирать правильный смысл.

Comment: «Репутацию должен получать непосредственно переводчик, после одобрения перевода, т.е. один и тот-же вопрос может быть переведен несколькими переводчиками и после "голосования" лучший перевод публикуется» — к сожалению, за репутацию хлеба не купишь. Сейчас вопросы доступны — знай переводи. Но почему-то никто не рвётся это делать. И тем более, нет конкурса, чтобы один вопрос несколько человек переводили и соревновались в качестве.

Comment: Когда вы выберете такой «лучший перевод» и отклоните ещё несколько, авторы тех переводов не получат ничего кроме фрустрации. Это на 100% не взлетит на волонтёрской тяге. Только деньги, много денег.

Comment: @NickVolynkin "нет конкурса, чтобы один вопрос несколько человек переводили и соревновались в качестве" так это же вроде как предложения?
"Это на 100% не взлетит на волонтёрской тяге. Только деньги, много денег." Так весь сайт на "волонтёрской тяге" или тут кто-то деньги получает и я чего-то не знаю?

Comment: @XelaNimed, "кто-то" определенно получает :-)

Comment: @XelaNimed дело вот какое: программистам обычно в кайф писать код. Некоторым из них в кайф отвечать на вопросы — из них состоит ядро участников SO. А вот таких, кому в кайф переводить чужие технические тексты, довольно мало. Особенно если твой перевод выкидывают как не-лучший, вот это вообще не в кайф.

Comment: @NickVolynkin так и ответы не все помечают как принятый. " А вот таких, кому в кайф переводить чужие технические тексты, довольно мало." но они есть и возможно даже в тельняшках :) Если не пробовать, то и не узнаем.

Answer (score 6):

В принципе и сейчас ничего не мешает брать топовые вопросы и ответы с enSO, переводить их, и грести репутацию лопатой. Но .. почему-то так никто не делает, несмотря на тривиальность и надежность способа. Почему так?

Предположения:

- может быть на самом деле способ ненадежный, и сотни голосов с enSO на ruSO не повторятся?
- вероятно нет чувства достижения цели всего лишь повторяя за кем-то их успехи?
- может быть способ не настолько очевиден или прост, чтобы тратить на него свое время?
- вероятно перевод хорошего вопроса и ответа не так прост и требует многих усилий (ведь хороший вопрос и ответ легко может быть на пару листов текста А4).

Если ruSO каким-либо существенным образом не предложит упростить данную задачу, никто ей всерьез не заинтересуется.

Как же упростить:

- поощрить сомневающихся - показать, что переводы и самоответы явно приветствуются (во втором, к примеру, до сих пор сомневаются).
- облегчить процесс перевода, предоставив инструменты для выбора вопроса/ответа по любимой теме, избегания дублей, параллельного просмотра текста, интегрировать словарь, визуализировать прогресс, добавить какие-то проверочные признаки качества (какие?).
- в то же время, предлагать автоперевод для причесывания и улучшения мне кажется опасным, т.к. это спровоцирует вал автопереводов с минимальной корректурой и кучей огрехов и ошибок - т.е. если это как следует не модерировать, то мы по факту лишь снизим качество Базы Знаний.

---

По просьбе из комментариев, конкретный *"минимальный набор функций движка, чтобы его можно было считать началом пути (и пользоваться)"* с точки зрения UX:

- Возможность в вопросе enSO нажать кнопку которая откроет интерфейс переводчика (с выбором сайта, куда перевод будет размещен) и предупредит об уже существующих дублях (чтобы пять раз не переводили один и тот же вопрос). В интерфейсе, по минимуму - слева оригинал вопроса с ответами, справа идентичные пустые поля для ввода текста (а-ля git merge). Логично, что переводиться будет вопрос и, например, 1 топовый ответ.
- Нужен механизм поддержания синонимов вопросов и их отображения в UI.

Comment: Спасибо! Несколько мыслей. Мне кажется, не ясно, с чего начать, поэтому не переводят. Не ясно, как отреагирует сообщество. Когда есть вопрос, на который ты знаешь ответ, всегда ясно, что делать и что будет. Кроме того, перевод действительно очень сложная задача. По вопросам с самоответом согласен. Надо освящать это дело. Вопрос к вам про «причесывание»: можно, например, отклонять перевод, каким–то похожем образом на отклонение правки. Вопрос, конечно довольно интересный и необходимо будет прийти к какому–то консенсусу о достаточном качестве перевода.

Comment: Это будет большое изменение для платформенного движка, так что наверняка его не получится сделать правильно ни с 1-го, ни с 4-го раза. Надо начинать и пробовать. Мульти-сайтовые синонимы, кнопка создания перевода с выбором куда, отдельная очередь переводов на утверждение, примерно в таком порядке, а там видно будет.

Comment: Не могли бы вы предложить какие–то конкретный минимальный набор функций движка, чтобы его можно было считать началом пути (и пользоваться)?

Comment: на самом деле большинство топовых уже и так переведено

Comment: @Grundy если вы в теме, уточните плиз (можно даже правкой), как это было сделано, кем, зачем и с какими итогами, дело заглохло или продолжается?

Comment: @Kromster, когда было мало вопросов - как раз просто брали топовые вопросы и переводили. Собственно, если посмотреть топовые вопросы тут - они в большинстве случаев будут переводами. Правда в некоторых случаях метка о переводе может отсутствовать

Comment: «Почему-то так никто не делает, несмотря на тривиальность и надежность способа» — потому что это адовый труд, такой же как просто взять и с нуля написать хороший вопросоответ. Я переводил и надеюсь когда-нибудь ещё попереводить. Но пока что побеждает работа, за которую платят деньги, которые нужны. Вот так всё прозаично. :)

Comment: Деньги деньгами, но мы то с вами знаем, что SO по факту наполнен альтруистами (чистыми и стремящимися за репутацией). Без них ни одного ответа бы не было вообще. Вот на них и надо рассчитывать ;-)

Comment: @Kromster да, но от альтруистов нельзя требовать какого-то уровня качества или производительности. А чтобы запустить эту идею, я думаю, нужно сразу выдать переводы для массы топовых вопросов и на высоком уровне качества. Волонтеры могли бы ревьюить такие переводы, но с нуля переводить и в больших количествах — сомневаюсь.

Comment: Ну то есть чтобы возглавить, захватить топ гугла по всем вопросам и выдавить оттуда сайты-паразиты, и всё это — силами переводчиков-людей. Это будет дорого. А вот с помощью машинного перевода эта задача становится уже реальной. И стоить это будет гораздо меньше.

Comment: @Kromster а ещё имеет значение специализация. Все наши альтруисты — в первую очередь разработчики, а переводить могут и хотят из них совсем немногие. Я бы скорее поверил, что мы коллективно напишем и обучим нейросеточку для переводов.

Comment: "Почему так?" Не интересно потомучто

Answer (score 5):

> Если представить, что завтра мы реализуем возможность работать с [автоматизированными как–либо] переводами, как будет выглядеть эта система в рамках Stack Overflow?

Для начала я бы хотел представить наличие на сайте дизайна, адаптированного для строк разной длины, которые в избытке появляются при переводе интерфейса. Но сейчас их приходится подтягивать под размеры английской фразы, дабы сайт более менее выглядел пристойно. Поэтому я не верю (не могу представить), что возможность работать с переводами появится на SO в каком-то обозримом будущем. Пока предложения на Area51 по созданию новых сайтов на языке, отличном от английского, не будут блокироваться автоматически (без рассмотрения) ни о каких других улучшениях, необходимых для неанглоязычных участников, говорить не приходится. Причём, что рассмотрение заявки сайта на Area51, что адаптивный (в плане различных языков) интерфейс требуют, имхо, значительно меньше усилий команды разработчиков SO нежели какой бы то ни было самый простой инструмент для появления переводов популярных англоязычных вопросов. Короче говоря, всё это слишком сомнительно. Тем не менее несколько идей могу высказать, в чём-то они пересекаются с уже имеющимися ответами.

#### Какую цель SO хочет достичь в борьбе с сайтами автоматических переводов?

Как я понимаю, если бы поисковик не выдавал такие сайты на позициях выше (локализованного) SO, то проблемы бы вовсе не было. Но коли уж она есть, то нужно покрыть качественными переводами в первую очередь тот контент, который даёт основную массу переходов из поисковика. Получить такую статистику можно либо от поисковика (вряд ли он её выдаст, к тому же по чужому сайту, но может быть есть какая-то лазейка?), либо от самого сайта автопереводов (совершенно однозначно не выдаст). Поэтому, чтобы сформировать список вопросов, требующих перевода нужно эту статистику собрать (и регулярно обновлять) самому. Например, предоставив возможность формировать общедоступный список ключевых фраз, когда поисковик выдаёт сайт автоперевода выше, чем локализованный SO. Из этих результатов можно сформировать другой список - вопросы, требующие перевода в приоритетном порядке.

#### Как переводить вопросы и ответы?

Когда список вопросов сформирован, можно предлагать участникам забронировать такой вопрос для перевода, если перевод не появится за определённое время, бронь надо снять (дополнительно можно ограничить возможность бронирования для такого участника в будущем, например, не разрешать бронировать какое-то кол-во дней). Одновременно разрешать только одну бронь на участника. Здесь стоит прояснить, что бронировать можно как вопрос/ответ одновременно, так и вопрос отдельно, ответ отдельно (при условии, что вопрос уже переведён). Например, кто-то может перевести короткие, но популярные (с точки зрения борьбы с сайтами автопереводов) вопросы, и это уже позволит увеличить кол-во потенциальных отвечающих. Кто-то может перевести имеющийся ответ (забронировав в соответствующей очереди), кто-то может дать свой ответ. Вероятность того, что свой ответ не будет пересекаться с имеющимся довольно мала (всё таки ссылка на оригинальный вопрос должна быть видна), но и такой возможности исключать не стоит. Вполне может статься, что русскоязычный разработчик предложит иной ответ, нежели был дан в оригинале.

#### Как быть с репутацией?

Всё, что я пока озвучил, не требует каких-либо изменений в механизме репутаций сайта. Переведённые вопросы и ответы публикуются наравне с обычными сообщениями, за тем лишь исключением, что должна присутствовать ссылка на оригинал и, вероятно, общая ссылка на весь инструментарий для переводов (очереди бронирования и т.п.), чтобы вовлекать новых участников в эту схему.

#### Что делать с переводами, если они появились минуя схему бронирования?

Если на сайте появляется перевод вопроса, который присутствует в списке требующих приоритетного перевода, и такой вопрос ещё никем не забронирован, то нужно будет лишь исключить его из списка (или пометить как готовый). Никаких санкций к переводчику быть не должно. Он сделал полезное дело, как это происходит иногда и сейчас. Если же перевод сделан для сообщения, которое забронировано на момент появления, такое сообщение следует удалить, как нарушающее систему переводов SO. Чтобы минимизировать кол-во ситуаций вида "ой, я не знал, что так надо", стоит рассмотреть добавление в список похожих вопросов (когда вводишь название темы) вопросов из очереди на перевод, тут вероятно надо всё же автоперевод подключить, но лишь для целей выхода на очередь переводов, на сайт автоперевод попадать не будет.

Учитывая, что желающих делать переводы не так много, можно вообще попробовать всю эту схему без каких-либо бронирований, но тогда вероятность создать дубликаты всё же несколько выше. А выкинуть половину перевода, если кто-то просто успел раньше - не очень приятно. Было такое как-то на мете со мной.

#### Что делать, если перевод получился недостаточного качества?

Плохой перевод получит свою порцию минусов, и может быть даже будет удалён коллективным голосованием или модератором. Сайт ничего не потеряет, а может быть даже на какое-то время приобретёт, если такой вопрос можно будет найти в гугле вместо автоперевода на стороннем сайте, а участник получит свои 15 минут позора. Тут за примерами далеко ходить не надо, достаточно вспомнить [вопрос о предсказателе переходов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/626264/176217). Если же перевод всё ещё можно относительно легко спасти, стоит внести улучшающие правки (совершенно обычные для сайта).

После всех этих выкладок, я даже несколько стал сомневаться, что задача будет неподъёмной и отложенной в дальний ящик для SO. Ведь изменений в движок можно вовсе не вносить: всё нужное держать по ссылкам в комментариях. Список сообщений для перевода расположить где-то рядом, но тем не менее на стороннем ресурсе, как это сейчас делается с системой переводов [traducir](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8256/176217), например.

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв! Список ключевых слов можно получить имея платную подписку на [Alexa](https://www.alexa.com/). Кроме того, раньше можно было вытащить статистику по посещениям вопросов на SOen русскоязычными разработчиками.  Эта статистика есть на [сайте ассоциаций](http://ru.rudevs.ru/). Замечания по блокировки очень интересные!  Как думаете, вы бы стали заниматься переводами, если бы предложенные в этом ответе вещи были сделаны на стороннем домене (например, как Traducir или ассоциации)?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky и то, и другое функционирует в достаточной степени. Не вижу причин, почему бы и переводам не работать.

Answer (score 3):

Мне кажется английский - это наиболее подходящий язык для IT и стоит идти не по-пути перевода с него на другие языки, а реализовать небольшую помощь тем, кто с ним не так хорошо знаком. В частности, перевод терминов и (в т.ч. сленговых) выражений. Навел мышкой на слово, тебе перевод-подсказка подсветилась. Это совсем не сложно и можно очень экономично реализовать без нейросетевых наворотов.

Comment: Спасибо, идея прекрасная! Мы ее уже начали реализовывать: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1267/6 Пожалуйста, добавляйте новые термины!

Comment: А смысл? У меня стоит Mate Translate- расширение для Google Chrome и я им перевожу то, что я не понимаю выделением и сочетание клавишь CTRL+T.

Comment: У меня тоже стоит стороннее приложение. Но 1) не всегда точный перевод (без IT контекста) 2) к переводу можно добавить расширенное определение термина (не просто варианты слов) + ссылку на доп поясняющие и интересные материалы по теме

Comment: @iluxa1810 у меня тоже стоит похожее расширение. А у других нет. И тысячи человек даже о нем не знают. И ставить расширение(а некоторые даже не знают, как это сделать) ради перевода пары слов им не захочется.

Answer (score 3):

Автопереводы не есть гуд, так как они местами убоги. За примерами далеко ходить не нужно и можно посмотреть MSDN, где они местами не читаемые. Имхо, нужно мотивировать делать ручные переводы.

**Я вижу это ~ так:**

При создании вопроса у нас будет доп. поле, куда можно поместить ссылку на исходный вопрос. После чего нажимаем на кнопку отправить вопрос и создается точная копия вопроса на английском языке, которая скрыта от посторонних глаз.

Далее, все это аккуратно переводится, добавляется конкретный ответ со ссылкой на источник и нажимается кнопка "Готов к публикации" и это попадает в очередь проверок, где вносятся правки.

Можно добавить еще доп. галку, что вопрос будет виден для других переводчиков, что бы они могли присоединиться.

**Зачем нужно сокрытие?**

Иногда текста достаточно много=> нужно дать время покумекать, что бы не показывать полуфабрикат.

Если все это успешно проверяется, то инициатор получает некоторый +N, далее все остальные за вклад тоже получают +N.

Если кому-то другому захочется перевести другой ответ к этому вопросу, то добавляет ответ и ссылается на исходный ответ. Он скрывается снова от посторонних глаз и переводится. Потом, когда это публикуют, то снова очередь проверок и все такое.

Иногда удобно видеть исходный текст и поэтому нужно сделать, как на MSDN- при наведении курсора сверху появляется аналог на английском.

Comment: Вообще-то ручной перевод противоречит идее показывать оригинальный текст, поскольку исчезает маппинг предложений.

Answer (score 2):

Я против переводов, я за свои тексты.

Не забывайте, что кроме собственно текстов, нам как бы еще сиёбщество развивать/поддерживать надо. В теории тут понятно: качественное сообщество пишет качественные тексты, качественные тексты привлекают качественных членов. В жизни не все так розово, но в целом как-то так. Главная ценность в том, что кроме самих знаний, еще есть те, кто ими владеет и, более того, готов за бесплатно, то есть даром, знаниями делиться.

Так вот, если тексты будут готовые, такие что нужно просто перевести, то тут не айтишники нужны, а переводчики. Ничего против них не имею, кого знаю, классные ребята, но это другая квалификация. А пацанам нечего делать будет, уйдут. Тут и так возгласы раздаются, что много шлака от начинающих, и что не интересно.

Теперь про сайты с автопереводами, я ж так понял они имеются ввиду. Самое опасное для РУСО, что гугл, например, выдает в топе русский автоперевод, если запрос введен на английском! При этом исходный английский текст с СО тоже часто в топе, но ниже автоперевода. Опасность в том, что те кто ищет по-английски находит русский автоперевод, перейти на который весьма соблазнительно. Но с одним большим НО! Если есть вариант на русском с нашего РУСО, у гугла он в топе как положено и выше всего остального!

Отсюда явно видно, что истинная проблема в том, что у нас недостаточно полные материалы. Не все вопросы покрываются, а точнее не все *формулировки* вопросов. На самом то деле эти гуглы с яндексами тоже далеки от идеала, они часто не находят вопросы, которые сформулированы по-другому. Поэтому правильнее говорить не об отдельном вопросе, а о проблеме, которая по-разному сформулирована.

Покрытие у нас определяется тем самым отношением 20/80, то есть 80% к 20% материалов. И я думаю, что наше сообщество достаточно зрелое и содержит те самые 20% вопросов и ответов. А вот по "формулировкам" мы проигрываем.

Comment: Большое спасибо! В целом, в компании полностью разделяют вашу точку зрения: самое главное — сообщество. С другой стороны, переводы — это что–то, что уникально для всех, чей первый язык не английский. Мы все все время так или иначе переводим или работам с переводами. Очень интересно, возможно и нужно ли создавать отдельные инструменты для международных сайтов на эту тему. Что думаете?

Answer (score 1):

В сентябре 2018 года был на мероприятии Яндекса, слушал доклад о том, как они [используют машинный перевод для своей документации](https://events.yandex.ru/lib/talks/6426/). В этой области всё уже довольно хорошо и становится только лучше. Есть такие ограничения:

- Для хорошего качества перевода нужно обучать нейросеть на базе, переведённой профессиональным переводчиком. Но корпус переведённых технических текстов уже есть.
- Тексты на stakoverflow гораздо менее стандартизованы, чем документация какой-нибудь компании Х. На SO пишут как хотят, с опечатками и сленгом. Так что качество будет пониже.
- Перевод стоит денег.

Имхо, стоит пробовать.

Вообще, если у StackOverflow взлетит этот проект, то потенциально это будет сайт с вопросами и ответами НА ВСЕХ языках. Круче, чем Википедия.

Comment: "сайт с вопросами и ответами НА ВСЕХ языках" сделанных нейронкой обученной на вопросах типа тех что щас на первой странице (т.е. 40% ниже среднего) с соответствующими косяками в переводах. Я настроен скептично :-/

Comment: @Kromster Яндекс свою документацию на украинский язык уже полностью переводит нейросетью. И нормально, качество устраивает. И скорость перевода условно моментальная.

Comment: @Kromster ну и обучать-то её не на наших вопросах надо. У нас тут нет дословно переведённых вопросов. Вместо этого есть корпус технических текстов, переведённых 1) дословно и 2) профессиональными переводчиками.

Comment: Видео не могу пока посмотреть. Но, могу предположить, что качество оригинальной документации соответствует неким хорошим стандартам и достаточно однородно и однотипно и в то же время примитивно, не содержит высоких концепций. То есть по сути, они имеют Google Переводчик расчитанный на однородные санитаризированные входные данные.

Comment: @Kromster да, всё так, в документации текст получше. Но всё равно стоит пробовать. Если не пробовать, так можно и проспать все полимеры, и потерять место лучшего сайта вопросов и ответов.

Comment: Слишком рискованная идея имхо. Подписываться на некий закрытый продукт с неизвестными перспективами. *минус не мой, если что.

Comment: В любом случаи можно пробовать и рассматривать идею. Но перевод на турецкий у яши это ужас.....

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev а что это за яша или яши? Ну и у турецкого наверняка сильно меньше корпус для обучения, чем у русского.

Comment: Спасибо! Подскажите, как вы видите интеграцию переводов в Stack Overflow? Было бы здорово, если бы вы как–то показали как примерно решить вопросы авторства, поддержки содержимого и тд. Вопрос очень интересен и во всех деталях. Например, как оказалось, на Википедии есть автоматические переводы, но реализованы они в виде помощника для написания статьи, который автоматизирует / помогает, но не заменяет человека: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Content_translation

Comment: @NickVolynkin яша - это яндекс

Comment: Я бы посмотрел на SO на коми-зырянском языке, только жаль не верится, что Яндекс, как и другие IT-гиганты, с его замечательными нейросетями интересуется переводами иными, нежели En-Ru, Fr-Ru (?). Google экспериментирует с чуть большим числом языков, но говорить О ВСЕХ языках, мягко говоря, наивно.

Answer (score 1):

Идея для интерфейса выбора вопроса для перевода - должно быть что-то похожее на очередь проверок.

Вопросы идут лентой, если человек хочет взять вопрос на перевод, то нажимает соответствующую кнопку(и у него открывается отдельная страница с вопросом-ответами и отдельная страница с пустыми диалоговыми полями, для ввода переводов), если нет - пропустить. Если человек взял вопрос на перевод, то этот вопрос должен пропасть из ленты.

Как подбирать вопросы - наверное по репутации, исключая те, для которых есть ассоциации. 
Так же, есть много вопросов, для которых нет ассоциаций, но которые не надо переводить. Поэтому для каждого вопроса в ленте переводов должна быть кнопка сделать ассоциацию(или убрать из ленты).

У участников с репой >3к(например) должна быть возможность удалить вопрос из ленты.

Еще должна проверятся корректность переводов - тоже можно взять идею из правок, два(или три) человека должны проверить перевод на корректность.

В ленте нет возможности взять нескольким людям один вопрос на перевод - т.к. мне не кажется, что это хорошая идея. Возникнет путаница, и т.п.

Стоит награждать переводчиков репутацией - 15 за перевод хватит. Почему 15 - потому что если перевод хороший, то заплюсуют и вопрос и ответы которые он перевел. Почему тогда вообще стоит награждать репой - мало ли что, вдруг ни кто не поставит плюс, тогда человеку расхочется переводить вопросы.